# Changing default rebase-merge directory to avoid backups from 'locking' the directory from deletion

Tags: git

**Summary:** Is there a way to not have the `rebase-merge` directory appear inside the `git` directory?

**Background:**
I have an automatic file backup running, courtesy of Google Drive. Since there is no way to tell Google Drive to exclude certain subdirectories, I've done the following:

I have a 'working directory' where I have all my checked out files, node_modules and stuff. This stuff is 'work in progress' and should NOT be backed up. The key is that my git files DO NOT live here, or they would not be backed up. Instead, I have a file, .git, which points at the git directory that contains all the checked in and commit code.

```
# Directory:
C:\<path to not backed up work directory>\MyProject\.git

# File Content:
gitdir: C:\<path to backed up root dir>\MyProject\git
```

This works great. My backups backs up any changes to my git directory, but leaves my checked-out files and working directory alone.

**The problem:**

If I do a rebase, git creates a directory here:

```
C:\<path to backed up root dir>\MyProject\git\rebase-merge
```

My automatic backup immediately starts backing that up. Worse, it has some kind of hold on it so that git cannot automatically remove it. So, after each rebase, I have to go in there and remove the directory manually.

**The Question:**
Is there a way to tell git to use a different directory for 'temporary' files and directories, such as `rebase-merge`?